# Search form flights with multiple params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a trip agency search form. I need the user to be able to enter an origin and a destination and have the search form return all the flights that match those conditions.

I'm trying to do it with RoR but I'm new to it and I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance¡¡

This is what I have tried.

My search form in the view is like this

```
<%= form_tag summary_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>Origin</p>
    <%= label_tag(:origin) %>
    <%= text_field_tag (:origin), params[:origin] %>
    <p>Destination</p>
    <%= label_tag(:destination) %>
    <%= text_field_tag (:destination), params[:destination] %>

    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: 'nil' %>
    <% end %>
```

This is the code of Flight Model Object

```
def self.search(origin,destination)
    #The result of the search has to be all the flights that have the origin and destinations entered by user
    where("origin like ?", "%#{origin}%").where("destination like ?", "%#{destination}%")
end
```

This is the code in the Flight Controller action

```
def show
    if params[:origin, :destination]
        @flights = Flight.search(params[:origin, :destination])
    else
        @alert = "Sorry, there are no results"
    end
end
```

And this is my databse. By the moment I just have two fights but I'll add more

```
Flight.create origin: 'Madrid', destination: 'Paris', price: 95, from_date: DateTime.new(2014, 11, 06, 10, 30), to_date: DateTime.new(2014, 11, 06, 12, 30), duracion: 2, aerolinea: 'DMS Trips', country: 'España'
Flight.create origin: 'Paris', destination: 'Madrid', price: 95, from_date: DateTime.new(2014, 11, 06, 10, 30), to_date: DateTime.new(2014, 11, 06, 12, 30), duracion: 2, aerolinea: 'DMS Trips', country: 'Francia'
```

Comment: So what's your problem? Where is your code failing?

Comment: I didn't know how to pass 2 params (origin and destination). I need the function to get all the flights that match with the origin and the destination introduced in the search form by the user. And it has to be both of them, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access two keys of the `params` hash at once. You need to check and pass the parameters individually.

```
if params[:origin] && params[:destination]
  @flights = Flight.search(params[:origin], params[:destination])
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. The console tells me no implicit conversion of nil into String. It doesn't get the object Flight.

Comment: Interesting. Did you modify the code in both places (in the condition and in the method call to `search`)?

Comment: Yes , I did just like you told me. I modified the controller like you told me. But I haven't changed anything in the model Flight. I'm not sure if I should modify something.

Comment: Ok I finally fixed it. The problem was that in the view I had flight.aerolinea and there was one flight that had'n got :aerolinea (aerolinea=>nil) so thats why it didn't work.   Thank you very much¡¡¡